# Reset fields using sweet alert in Angular 6

Tags: angular, sweetalert

After clicking on reset a popup should ask whether you want to reset the fields or not (done because number of fields are high).

**Code**

**In .html**

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="showAlert()">Reset</button>
```

**In .ts**

```js
declare var swal: any;
import * as $ from 'jquery';
showAlert() {
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "you want to reset",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Reset it!'
  }).then(function(){
    //what to do here
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it**

```
.then(()=> {
  this.myMethod();
})
  myMethod()
{
 $('#Formid').trigger("reset");
}
```

Removed Function name from head and used separate function